# Is this an application of the Chinese Remainder Theorem?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, chinese-remainder-theorem

I've been having some issues with the following problem for a few days, and I think I might have found the answer, but I'm not quite sure:

**Problem**: Let f(x) be a polynomial with integer coefficients. Assume integer $m$ exists such that $f(m) \equiv 0\ (mod \ 10) $ and integer $n$ exists such that $f(n) \equiv 0\ (mod \ 33)$. Integers $m$ and $n$ do not have to be equal. Must there exist some integer $q$ such that $f(q) \equiv 0\ (mod\ 330)$? Why or why not?

I understand that, by principle, the equation f(x) would have to include 330 as a possible divisor considering it contains the components that generate both 10 and 33, but I'm confused as to why that is. Am I able to use the Chinese Remainder Theorem to say that since all of the congruences are using the same function of $f(x)$, by the CRT, there must exist an integer $q$ such that $f(q) \equiv 0\ (mod\ (33*10))$?

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Explain in more detail *how* you are using the CRT. Write down the actual argument! (Yes, your solution will use it.)

Comment: So, the CRT states that if the mod values of two or more congruences are pairwise relatively prime (10 and 33 are pairwise relatively prime since the only common positive factor of both is 1), then there does exist a value of x satisfying the simultaneous congruences $f(x) \equiv 0\ (mod 10)$ and $f(x) \equiv 0\ (mod 33)$, where f(x) is unique modulo 10*33. This therefore means that there exists a unique value, $f(q)$ say, that is congruent to 0 mod 330.

Comment: The one thing I was concerned about was the use of f(x) in the theorem - say a congruence exists such that $x \equiv y\ (mod\ n)$ as demonstrated in the definition of Chinese Remainder Theorem - does this still hold for $f(x)$ as well?

Comment: Re: the first sentence of your first comment: That's not what CRT says. CRT says that since 10 and 33 are relatively prime, there exists a $q$ such that $q\equiv m$ mod $10$ and $q\equiv n$ mod $33$. Now you have to prove, using that information, the existence of a $q$ mod $330$ for which $f(q)\equiv0$ mod $330$.

Comment: Sorry, that probably explains why I was having a tough time with this - that makes a little more sense. I had forgotten the CRT was used to solve linear congruences, so I went a little too far. So the CRT states that would be one integer value that would be congruent to both $m\ (mod\ 10)$ and $n\ (mod\ 33)$. Thus, that same value would be unique $mod\ 330$. So, now that we've determined this, we need to convert the congruencies to functions. Which brings us to my other question then - if $x \equiv y\ (mod\ n)$, what happens to f(x) or f(y) mod n?

Comment: If $a\equiv b$ and $c\equiv d$ mod $n$ then $a+c\equiv b+d$ and $ac\equiv bd$ mod $n$. (Since $\equiv$ plays so nicely with the operations of $+$ and $\times$, we call it a *congruence relation*.) Can you prove these two simple properties? Can you prove, using these two properties and some inductive thinking, that $x\equiv y$ implies $f(x)\equiv f(y)$ mod $n$ for any integer-valued polynomial $f$?

Comment: Right, I understand that you can add and multiply congruences together (the proofs are fairly obvious), which implies that a function of x should be congruent to the same function of y mod n (for a polynomial with integer coefficients). $f(x) \equiv f(y)\ (mod\ n)$. So, then we should be able to apply this to the CRT outlined above - $f(x) \equiv f(m)\ (mod\ 10)$ & $f(x) \equiv f(n)\ (mod\ 33)$ implies $f(x)$ is unique mod 330.

Comment: More than unique, $f(q)\equiv f(m)\equiv 0$ mod $10$ and $f(q)\equiv f(n)\equiv 0$ mod $33$ imply that $f(q)$ must be the unique residue mod $330$ which is $0$ mod both $10$ and $33$, and that residue is $0$ again. In other words, $f(q)\equiv0$ mod $10$ and mod $33$ (which both follow from $f(q)\equiv f(m),f(n)$ respectively) imply $f(q)\equiv0$ mod $330$.